# vaadin date picker to show month year only

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, vaadin-elements, vaadin-date-picker

I am using vaadin-date-picker to display the date. It's default format is `6/21/2017`. I want to show only month and year. Such as `jun 2017` or `6/2017`. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

`vaadin-date-picker` is using i18n property to localize everything. When declaring `vaadin-date-picker` element, you can also set i18n property. for Example:

```
<vaadin-date-picker i18n='[[i18nCustom]]'></vaadin-date-picker>
```

and then declare property:

```
i18nCustom: {
    value: function() {
        return  {

      week: 'viikko',
      calendar: 'kalenteri',
      clear: 'tyhjennä',
      today: 'tänään',
      cancel: 'peruuta',
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      monthNames: ['tammikuu','helmikuu','maaliskuu','huhtikuu','toukokuu','kesäkuu',
                   'heinäkuu','elokuu','syyskuu','lokakuu','marraskuu','joulukuu'],
      weekdays: 'sunnuntai_maanantai_tiistai_keskiviikko_torstai_perjantai_lauantai'.split('_'),
      weekdaysShort: ['su','ma','ti','ke','to','pe','la'],
      formatDate: function(d) {
        return [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
      },
      parseDate: function(text) {
        // This example produces a really strict parser which only accepts
        // perfectly formatted dates like '12.8.2013'. Less strict implementation or
        // a 3rd party parser like in the example below is recommended.
        var parts = text.split('.');
        if (parts.length === 3) {
          var date = new Date(0, 0);
          date.setFullYear(parseInt(parts[2]));
          date.setMonth(parseInt(parts[1]) - 1);
          date.setDate(parseInt(parts[0]));
          return date;
        }
      },
      formatTitle: function(monthName, fullYear) {
        return monthName + ' ' + fullYear;
      }
        }
    }
}
```

What you are looking for is function `formatDate`. Where you can edit what should be returned as displayed text

Comment: Wouldn't be a problem if you start the weekdays with Sunday, but the sort versions on Monday? `weekdays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
                        weekdaysShort: ["Mo", "Th", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],`

Comment: I have never realized i have bug in this. But i am using it for few months in production and no problems were found yet.

Comment: its giving error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: @Hassam try it now, if it's still throwing some error, try to update to newest version. This code is grabbed frm official documentation so it should work. Anyway, you can try it on yourself now, when you know how to do it. Just editing function formatDate is important